# Ext: bind formpanel after datastores for combo's have loaded

Tags: extjs

In an Ext Js-application I am working on I have a formpanel that contains (among other controls) three comboboxes, each with a different datastore. I need to load the form with existing data and display that in the form. This works for all simpel controls (textboxes, checkboxes) but there is a problem with the comboboxes.

The comboboxes each use a datastore but I can see that there is only one store loaded before the form loads its own data, causing that one combobox to display the correct text and the other two the value. If I click and close the combobox without making a selection the correct text appears.

Is there a way to either delay the loading of the form or the binding of the form until all datastores have loaded? The datastores are local stores with autoload and the formpanel calls its own load in the afterlayout-event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the setValue executed by loading your form is executed before the stores of the combo boxes are actually loaded.

You could try to implement the fix condor and animal of ExtJS have propsed in this forum thread on sencha.com: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?75751-OPEN-42-ComboBox-s-setValue-call-with-a-remotely-loaded-Store

It basically just delays the setValue call on any combobox until the store of the combobox is fully loaded.

Comment: Seems odd that a fix like this would be needed, I'd imagine this is a pretty common scenario. Or is the prefered way to use comboboxes on forms by using remote-type non-autoloading datastores? Documentation on this is pretty thin and I can't really figure out what the recommended way is to do these things...

Comment: You are not the first to notice this ... the implementation of combobox stores and their async natures is something that's been a point of discussion within the ext community for some time, the link i posted illustrates this as there are several requests to add the fixes to the official ext distribution. There are many area's in which ext can be improved but overall it's a wonderful system.

Answer (score 0):

Load the form panel after the rendering is complete. Is there any specific reason you are loading the form in afterlayout event?

Load the form in **afterrender** event rather than afterlayout. the afterrender event happens when all form is completely rendered.

Comment: it's not due to the rendering but due to the fact that the forms load action is executed before the three combobox stores are loaded. And due to the asynchronous nature of stores this is not very simple.